# material-components-web for vue js

Tags: vue.js, material-design, material-components-web

I have a website based on Vue framework and webpack.

I came across this css framework developed by Google (**Material Components Web**) where you can directly get started using a cdn or an npm package. It worked extremely well for a simple html/javascript based website. But, I am having issues setting it up for the Vue project.

There are other wrappers available for Vue framework like **Veutify** and **Vue Material**. But, it comes with lot of additional stuff like the grid layout which I don't want the developers to follow as we are already using a flex layout. I only want the component library.

So, is there a way use the Material Components Web with the Vue framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the **Material Components Web** working with the Vue framework. But I did found another light-weight material design framework i.e. [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/).

Note: It is not specific to any framework. It lets you add Material Design look to your website developed in any framework

You can easily get started with a wide variety of options like cdn, bower, npm or even by downloading the files.

Answer (score 0):

**Material Components Web** has modular architecture. Each component or API is distributed as a [separate package](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages). It means that you can use them separately, although there are some dependencies.

Also there is "root" package - [material-components-web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/material-components-web), which just references all other packages.

By default, when you add a package, it will not be included in your app. You'll need to import component's SCSS and optionally JavaScript. Basically like you would use any other component.

Reference this [Vue app template](https://github.com/kekscs/vue-material-layout-kit) as an example. As you can see [here](https://github.com/kekscs/vue-material-layout-kit/blob/master/src/vendor/mdc/material-components-web--theme-default.scss), it references only subset of MDC's components/APIs.